# How can I change the shortcut key for switching windows on a Mac?

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts

Right now, <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> cycles between windows. How can I rebind this to use <kbd>Alt</kbd> instead of <kbd>Command</kbd>?

I'm looking for a native solution which doesn't require 3rd party software.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you're an experienced Windows user, based on a few things in your question. First, <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> doesn't actually cycle between windows (like it does in Windows), rather, it activates the Application Switcher. Cycling through windows in a single application is done with <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> and <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>.

This behavior can be edited in System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts under Keyboard & Text Input (on 10.6).

I don't believe you can rebind the only the Application Switcher to <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, but you can rebind the <kbd>command</kbd> key entirely to <kbd>option</kbd>, if you chose. Also in the Keyboard System Preferences, this is in the Keyboard tab; click the "Modifier Keys..." button to show a sheet allowing you to change modifier bindings per keyboard.

On a Mac keyboard, assuming you're using one, however, the <kbd>command</kbd> key is in fact exactly where <kbd>alt</kbd> would be on a PC keyboard, so I can't think of a good reason for wanting to change this. Maybe you're using a PC keyboard with a Mac, in which case reassigning <kbd>alt</kbd> to <kbd>command</kbd> with the "Modifier Keys..." sheet is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah, I meant the Application Switcher, my bad. I'm using a PC keyboard, but I don't want to switch `alt` to `command` since 90% of the shortcuts are fine as they currently are. It's just this one that is bothering me at the moment.